# How to get dependency list in windows makefile

Tags: makefile, nmake

I have a linux makefile that I have to modify so that it compiles on windows with nmake and cl instead of gcc. From what I've seen in the make manual, $^ expands to the dependecy list for that given rule. However, it's not recognized by nmake. Could you please tell me the equivalent windows automatic variable?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cbes8ded.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot. The windows equivalent seems to be $**

Answer (score 0):

([Answered in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments))

@Etan Reisner wrote:

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cbes8ded.aspx

After reading the Microsoft manual, the OP concluded:

> The windows equivalent seems to be `$**`